# fabricjs - how can I unlock the aspect ratio

Tags: fabricjs

As far as I can tell, when using a corner control to resize an object, the height and width are changed proportionally maintaining the objects aspect ratio regardless of where the user moves the mouse.  My client wants the user to be able to adjust the height and width independently from the aspect ratio when using the corner controls.  Is there a setting that will allow that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while scaling.

OR

You can adding this code:

```
canvas.uniScaleTransform = true;
```

EDIT:

the property is now called as of Fabric.js 4.0

```
canvas.uniformScaling = false;
```

Comment: Thank you.  I never would have found that property.

Comment: Is it possible to control this on an object level? I only have some objects i want to adjust this way others I want the aspect ratio to be maintained

Answer (score 4):

By default, corner controls only resize and maintain aspect ratio.

You can turn off corner controls using [setControlsVisibility](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#setControlsVisibility), like this:

```
object.setControlsVisibility({
    tl: false, //top left
    tr: false, //top right
    bl: false, //bottom left
    br: false //bottom right
});
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/da7L0n1e/1/

Comment: Saying the corners resize maintaining aspect ratio by default implies to me that might be changed.  Can it be changed and if so, how? My client wants to use the corner controls and not be restricted to maintaining aspect ratio